# How to assign role and web page permission to a user using aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my Web App I have the ability to create a user and role.  But what I would like to do now is to assign a page to that user in that role.

So for example:

User1 is in role "Clients" and can only have access to WebForm1.aspx

As per below:

[image]

I guess I need to save the webpages locations in my database and link the user and role to that page and then check in the page load event what user is logged in to redirect them to that page only?

The problem is I am not sure on how to achieve this.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Updated Code:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void btnLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName.Text, true);
            Session["UserName"] = this.UserName.Text.Trim();
            CheckPermission();

            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, RememberMe.Checked);


        }

        // If we reach here, the user's credentials were invalid
        InvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
    }

    public string GetUserPage(string userId)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DEV\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SecurityDB;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM aspnet_Permissions WHERE UserId = @userId", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (row["FilePath"] != null)
            {
                return row["FilePath"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void CheckPermission()
    {
        var userPage = GetUserPage(User.Identity.Name);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userPage))
        {
            Response.Redirect("/NotAllowed");
        }
        if (Request.RawUrl != userPage)
        {
            Response.Redirect(userPage);
        }
    }
}
```

In my data base table `aspnet_Permissions` I have the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID    |  UserId  | FilePath                                         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | 123Admin | C:\Users\Development\Web\Clients\123.aspx        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I try and log in now with user `123Admin` I get redirected to the "Not Allowed Page"

I understand the concept now better but not sure why it isn't working now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a Permission table in your database which contains UserId and Path of your page. When the user logins, you can get her permission and cache it (you can refresh it every few minutes if you want). Then every time the user wants to load a page, you check her permissions and show her the page or redirect the request to a "not allowed" page or her own page.

You can also do this by defining roles for users and giving permission to that role.

**Update:**
You should add a method in your Data Access Layer to get permitted page:

```
public string GetUserPage(string userId)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Permission Where UserId = @userId", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (row["Page"] != null)
        {
            return row["Page"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And create a helper method to call it and check the permission, because you gonna use it several times:

```
public void CheckPermission()
{
    var userPage = GetUserPage(User.Identity.Name);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userPage))
    {
        Response.Redirect("/NotAllowed");
    }
    if (Request.RawUrl != userPage)
    {
        Response.Redirect(userPage);
    }
}
```

You can Check Permission in page_load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckPermission();
    //your other codes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  Although I am not sure how to implement it though :-(  Is there a tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: @EllenSellers You mean you want a pre-written implementation?

Comment: I have managed to save the username and webpage into the database now.  But just need to know how to redirect that user to that page saved in the database

Comment: @EllenSellers I added some code to clarify what I meant. Does it help?

Comment: I have updated my question, but it still doesn't seem to work :-( I understand what you are saying, and as I read the code I see that it should work.  But its not working its redirects me to the "Not Allowed Page"

Comment: @EllenSellers You shouldn't store the file path like that. It should be a relative address like /Default or /Default.aspx. If you debug your code and put a breakpoint in **CheckPermission** you gonna find out what's your RawUrl  and then you should store page address just like that.